# error: unpack failed: error Object too large (1,957,642 bytes), rejecting the pack. Max object size limit is 1,048,576 bytes

Tags: git, squarespace

I am getting this error when trying to push to my repo. Anyone know what could be causing it?

error: unpack failed: error Object too large (1,957,642 bytes), rejecting the pack. Max object size limit is 1,048,576 bytes.
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))

Answer (score 1):

The maximum file size you can upload to Squarespace using Git is 1MB

Comment: Make sure each file inside your git repository is below 1MB

Comment: I deleted the file that was larger than 1MB, commited the change, but when I push I still get the same "Object too large" error -- any idea why it is still getting picked up?

Comment: if you delete the file and create a new commit, the file will still exist in git history. The solution is either squash the commits or amend it.